# Why is it rational that salt-bridges (in proteins) are described as a combination of H-bond and ionic bond?

Tags: bond, biochemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, proteins, amino-acids

This is a fundamental question that came to me as I was trying to draw the electrostatic attraction between Aspartate (D) and lysine (K). I have always considered the charge on nitrogen, in the lysine side-chain (-NH3+), as a real charge. This is because it has always been described to me as an ionizable amino-acid, that can form salt-bridges to carboxylic anions e.g. aspartate (D) or glutamate (E).

**The general definition of a salt-bridge is**:  *a strong electrostatic attraction, a combination of H-bond and an ionic-bond*. This is simple enough to memorize and makes sense when one is studying enzyme structure. However, as I started to draw this salt-bridge attraction between lysine (K) and aspartate (D) - it started to seem counter intuitive that a salt-bridge is a type of ionic-bond, as the hydrogens on nitrogen seem to be in the way? I also started to wonder when the charge on nitrogen is real, or simply a formal charge.

[image: salt-bridgee]

**Questions on the the definition of salt-bridges in proteins**:

- Why is a salt-bridge not just simply a hydrogen bond (i.e. not partially ionic)?
- If I accept the notion that this is (partially) an ionic bond, how can I tell that there is a real charge on the nitrogen (an not just simply a formal charge)? And furthermore, why won’t the hydrogens (protons) on the ammonium group ‘disrupt’ the ionic attraction?
- Is there, perhaps, a defining bond energy that would classify it as ionic (and it happens to be just within this?) otherwise we would simply call it a hydrogen bond?

I also noted that the question is very similar to [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60113/salt-bridge-vs-hydrogen-bond) , but it does not really highlight how salt-bridges are a combination of both H-bonds and ionic-bond.

Comment: "It also assumes salt-bridges as purely ionic" - no, not really, just poorly worded. If you read answers properly, it may clear it up a bit. Also your wordiness here obfuscates points of questions.

Comment: point taken, ill rephrase. My point here was that the linked question (not the answers)  is not focusing on 'the combination of H-bond and ionic-bond' confusion. I dont understand how this could be called an ionic bond.

Comment: Actually that's perhaps more of an ionic bond then what is commonly ascribed as such - even in something like KF covalent component is significant and here, it tenuous. If not hydrogen bond, it would be almost pure ionic interaction.

Comment: Another thing is that this picture is overdone, hurts eyes a bit. While bifurcated h-bonds are of course possible, it's not one of these cases. There would be just one, generic bond, two at most.

Comment: For two bonds, asp:arg is a good pair